# Mysql workbench Error 1215 : cannot add foreign key to constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So Im trying to add a foreign key to table but keep getting this error :

*Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint*

The code is as follow

```
create table Students

(
    ID char(10) primary key not null,
    StudentsName varchar(30),
    Address varchar(40),
    StudentsTelephone varchar(20),
    constraint M1 check(len(NIM)=10),
    constraint M2 check(NIM like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)

create table Lecturers

(
    CodeLecturer char(5) primary key not null,
    LecturersName varchar(30),
    Salary numeric,
    Address varchar(40),
    LecturerTelephone varchar(20),
    constraint D1 check(len(CodeLecturer)=5),
    constraint D2 check(CodeLecturer like 'D[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

)
```

This is the foreign key code

```
create table TrHeaderKampus

(
    TransactionCOde char(5) primary key not null,
    ID char(10) not null,
    CodeLecturer char(5) not null,
    DateandTime datetime,
    constraint H1 check(len(TransactioniCode)=5),
    constraint H2 check(TransactionCode like 'TR[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    foreign key(ID)REFERENCES Students ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    foreign key(CodeLecturer)REFERENCES Lecturers ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: What are `MsMahasiswa` and `MsDosen` in the references section of the foreign key? Do you know that MySQL parses check constraint, but does not execute them?

Comment: Edited it out. It was supposed to be `Students` and `Lecturers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on [using foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) explains: you need to provide not only the table, but also the field(s) that the foreign key references.

> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>     [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>     REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>     [ON DELETE reference_option]
>     [ON UPDATE reference_option]
> ```

Add the name of the fields to the foreign key constraints that they reference.

Comment: Funny. Ive been staring at that webpage for hours before I posted here.. Baka des

Comment: I know this feeling :)